# Duvida sobre SQL

Tags: sql, select, join, inner-join, inner

Boa tarde pessoal, estou aprendendo SQL e tenho que fazer um exercicio que é:
**Selecionar o nome e sobrenome dos empregados e consultores que trabalham no departamento “Financeiro”**.

Acontece que eu estou tentando usar essa query

```
SELECT nmemp, snemp, nmconsult FROM emp, consult 
WHERE consult.coddepto = emp.coddepto AND
emp.coddepto in(Select coddepto from depto where nmdepto = 'financeiro')
```

Tentei usar join tambem mas não adiantou

```
SELECT nmemp, snemp,nmconsult FROM emp 
LEFT JOIN consult ON consult.coddepto = emp.coddepto 
LEFT JOIN depto ON  nmdepto = 'financeiro' AND consult.coddepto = depto.coddepto
```

O resultado esta dando errado como na imagem abaixo, gostaria de saber o que estou errando,
pois não estou conseguindo encontrar meu erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Abaixo segue as imagens com os nomes das tabelas que precisam ser usadas**

Nome da tabela = consult
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNnI4.png

Nome da tabela = depto
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tna7.png

Nome da tabela = emp
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCnf6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver este problema existem duas alternativas. A primeira seria fazer as consultas em separado e usar UNION ALL para juntar os resultados das duas tabelas. A consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT nmconsult as nome, snconsult as sobrenome from consult where coddepto in (SELECT coddepto from depto where nmdepto = 'financeiro')
UNION ALL 
SELECT nmemp as nome, snemp as sobrenome from emp where coddepto in (SELECT coddepto from depto where nmdepto = 'financeiro')
```

O UNION ALL serve para estes casos onde você quer juntar o resultado de consultas que tem a mesma quantidade de colunas e a mesma ordem e tipo de dados em cada coluna.

Outra alternativa seria, também utilizando o UNION ALL, juntar os resultados das consultas e aplicar o filtro por departamento no final. A consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT nmconsult as nome, snconsult as sobrenome, coddepto from consult
UNION ALL 
SELECT nmemp as nome, snemp as sobrenome, coddepto from emp
) as tabela where coddepto in (SELECT coddepto from depto where nmdepto = 'financeiro')
```

Neste exemplo, foi atribuído o apelido (alias) "tabela" aos resultados das duas consultas. Desta forma, se pode aplicar filtros aos resultados.

Comment: Muito obrigado, fiquei lendo a query aqui e agora entendi como funciona o UNION ALL, no começo eu estava com dificuldades de usar ele agora com sua explicação consegui compreender bem, muito obrigado